# Makefile: Could not find class file for 'menuEditor.GuiRenderJNI''

Tags: makefile, java-native-interface

I have a class file called GuiRenderGUI in a folder called menuEditor. I've checked the spelling and that the files all exist yet I still cannot build a .h file.

I've tried all permutations of my classpath being ../bin or ../bin/menuEditor and the class being GuiRenderJNI or .menuEditor.GuiRenderJNI, the code below is the one with the "could not find..." error, all other permutations simply say 'No rule to make target `GuiRenderJNI.class'

```
# Define a variable for classpath
CLASS_PATH = ../bin/menuEditor

# Define a virtual path for .class in the CLASS_PATH directory
vpath %.class $(CLASS_PATH)

# $* matches the target filename without the extension
GuiRenderJNI.h : GuiRenderJNI.class
    javah -classpath $(CLASS_PATH) menuEditor.$*

clean :
    rm GuiRenderJNI.h GuiRenderJNI.o guirender.dll
```

What am I doing wrong? I can't find the problem in my code!

---

EDIT:

- I've managed to get javah to generate a header file by making it look for the class inside a .jar file, using the exact same parameters, save for the -classpath which pointed to the .jar, if that helps

Comment: For the record `$*` being the target filename without the extension is a GNU make compatibility feature that the manual recommends not using. In general `$*` is the `stem` with which a implicit (pattern) rule matched.

Comment: If you found an answer that satisfies you should post it as an answer and accept it.

Comment: I haven't found an answer that satisfies the question. I shouldn't have to package the .class file into a .jar file to get it to work...

Comment: That would be why I said `if`. Does `-classpath` accept relative paths like that (I assume yes since you said it works with a jar). Does using `$(abspath $(CLASS_PATH))` in that `javah` line change anything?

Comment: `-classpath` does accept relative paths, and sadly `$(abspath...` doesn't work either, going to try a few of your suggestions in your answer below now, can't believe I didn't realise I was asking it to look for the .class inside the .class file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think the issue here is the difference between how `vpath` interprets its argument and how `javah` does (when looking for `.class` files as opposed to when looking for `.jar` files).

When you say `vpath %.class $(CLASS_PATH)` you are telling make that for any prerequisites that match the pattern `%.class` it should look for them (via the filename it started with) under `$(CLASS_PATH)`.

When you say `-classpath $(CLASS_PATH)` you are telling java to use `$(CLASS_PATH)` as the root path for finding `.class` and `.jar` files. However the way it uses that root path differs depending on which of those two types of files you are looking for.

When looking for jar files java uses the root path and looks for files named after the package/module/whatever. So `javah -classpath /foo menuEditor.GuiRenderJNI` will look for `/foo/menuEditor.GuiRenderJNI.jar` (I believe, I'm not a java person). (So I presume when you got it working you had created a `menuEditor.GuiRenderJNI.jar` file, or something close to that.)

When looking for class files java uses the root path as the start of a directory hierarchy with components based on the class name components. So `javah -classpath /foo menuEditor.GuiRenderJNI` will look for `/foo/menuEditor/GuiRenderJNI.class`.

Putting those together when you have a `$(CLASS_PATH)` of `../bin/menuEditor` you are telling make to look for `GuiRenderJNI.class` in `../bin/menuEditor/GuiRenderJNI.class` which it can find. (This is why the other values for `$(CLASS_PATH)` gave you "no rule to make target" errors since it couldn't find that class file anymore.)

That same classpath however (combined with that `javah` call) tells java to look for `../bin/menuEditor/menuEditor/GuiRenderJNI.class` which, for obvious reasons, cannot be found.

If `javah` will let you under-specify the class to operate on you might be able to use `javah -classpath $(CLASS_PATH) $(basename $@)` (non-compat target-without-suffix, also `$(@:.h=)` would work).

If `javah` will not let you do that then you either need to mangle `$(CLASS_PATH)` for the `javah` command line (something like `$(dir $(CLASS_PATH))`).

You could also try (and I don't know that `vpath` works like this but I believe it does) pulling `menuEditor` out of `$(CLASS_PATH)` and putting it in the prereq for that target `GuiRenderJNI.h: menuEditor/GuiRenderJNI.class` and then leaving `$(CLASS_PATH)` as-is on the `javah` line.

Comment: The very last solution you suggested worked like a charm, thank you.